# Git: Insert my work into two commits

Tags: git, git-commit

I'm pretty new to Git and I think I created a mess in my master branch.

Here's what happened:

I was working (peacefully and without messing with anybody) and I got my commits like this.

```
a --> b --> C --> D
```

`a, b` being commits from other people, and `C` and `D` being my commits. I pushed all to our main repository and an automatic tool we have to run tests on every push said that the build was failing. So I panicked. I created a new directory and re-cloned the repository until commit `b` (when that automated tool was saying that the build was ok) made some very small changes and *forced* a push (yeah, not very clever of me, but it was late and I was freaking out) so at that point, the remote repository looked like this:

```
a --> b --> E
```

But it turns out that my initial commits `C` and `D` were correct, and it was the automated tool who failed. It was giving false positives!! When I realized, someone had commited again to the main branch (remote repository), so at this point it looks like this.

```
a --> b --> E --> f
```

What I want to do is safely and without destroying my coworker's work insert my good commits `C` and `D` into the branch. I still have those commits in a directory within my computer, but as soon as I do a `git pull`, they'll be destroyed.

I would like the remote repository to look something like:

```
a --> b --> C --> D --> f
```

or

```
a --> b --> f --> C --> D
```

or even

```
a --> b --> E --> f --> C --> D
```

(keeping the super-dummy commit `E`, I don't mind)

Basically, I want `C` and `D` there, without destroying my coworker's `f` commit.

Is this even possible to do?

I'm in a panic mode so anything would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `C` and `D` back [edit: if you had "lost" them in your original repo, but I see you haven't].  Use `git reflog` to find them by ID:

```
$ git reflog
```

or:

```
$ git reflog master
```

(if you were on `master` and just want to see the changes that happened there), etc.

Once you find commit `D`, stick a branch label on it.  Let's say that the output from the above makes it clear that `HEAD@{3}` is the one you want.  Then:

```
$ git branch recover_my_stuff 'HEAD@{3}'
```

or:

```
$ git branch get_d_back 0123456
```

to do it by number (and with a different name and so on).  You can run `gitk HEAD@{3}` and `gitk 0123456` before this, or `git log HEAD@{3}`, etc., to double check whether that's the one you want.  Once you have a branch label on it, `git branch` and `gitk --all` will show it to you again.

---

Edit: since you still have them in the original repo, let's work in there instead.  First, your `master` currently has the `a - b - C - D` sequence.  Let's rename this branch to `temp`, then use `git fetch` to get up to date with the remote repo, and create a new `master` that tracks `origin/master`:

```
$ git branch -m master temp
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout -b master --track origin/master
```

(Here, `temp`—since it's just a rename of the original `master`—will "track" `origin/master` too, so git will tell you that it's different from `origin/master`, being both ahead and behind by several commits.  But you don't need to care, you can ignore these notices from git.  If you like, you can make it stop "tracking" by editing the git config, but it will all be harmless either way.)

---

OK, so, let's say you've got the above done, and `gitk` now shows (in a more pretty graphical form) this.  I'll use the branch label `temp` for the recovered stuff, and assume the rest is all on `master` (well, you said it was :-) ):

```
a - b - E - f         <-- HEAD=master, origin/master
      \
        C - D         <-- temp
```

In general it's not nice to "rewind" branch labels on other people (it's OK to do it to yourself :-) ) so let's leave `E` in there.  You can at any point `git revert` it to add a commit that simply un-does whatever `E` did.  All you need to do now is graft copies of `C` and `D` on top of `f`.  This is what `git rebase` does: it copies the changes in the original commits, to new commits.  Then it moves the label.

```
$ git checkout temp
$ git rebase master
```

Now you'll have this:

```
a - b - E - f         <-- master, origin/master
     \       \
      \       C'-D'   <-- HEAD=temp
       \
        C - D          [no branch label]
```

(since C and D have no label, they will disappear from `gitk --all`.  You can put another label back on them again, if you want to see them, but you don't need them anymore now that you have the copies.)

Now all you have to do is bring `master` forward, which you can do with `git merge`.  First you have to `git checkout master` (there's a way to do this without the intermediate step but let's keep it simple):

```
$ git checkout master

a - b - E - f         <-- HEAD=master, origin/master
             \
              C'-D'   <-- temp
```

This is the same commit diagram, we just changed where HEAD points (to master) and dropped the invisible commits.

```
$ git merge temp
```

The `merge` op will "fast-forward" master, as the only thing needed to achieve the merge is to "slide the label down" from commit `f` to commit `D'`:

```
a - b - E - f         <-- origin/master
             \
              C'-D'   <-- HEAD=master, temp
```

Now you can `git branch -d temp` to delete the temporary branch, and `git push origin master` to push.

---

Side note: congrats on drawing clear examples of what the commit graph looks like now, and what you want it to look like.  That's about 80% of all the work needed to figure out which git commands to use. :-)

Comment: Great answer... Saved my butt :)

Comment: Too-late note (I wrote the above before running off all day, and realized you had a repo with the right stuff on `master` already, a bit late and edited it in): [felipec's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19075039/1256452), `git pull --rebase`, is a lot easier in that particular case.  Mine is more for "after you already discarded some commits, resynched with the remote, and then realize your first work was correct after all".

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
git pull --rebase
```

Note that a 'git pull' won't destroy your local commits, it will create a merge, which is probably not want you want.

Comment: That's odd... I tried that. I copied my directory to a backup, tried that, and I would swear that my C and D commits were deleted.

Comment: They shouldn't, the result should be:
a --> b --> E --> f --> C --> D